# Should it be obvious that this integral is zero?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, gaussian-integral

The Gaussian integral is

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\pi} &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm d x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} 2\, e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm d x
\end{align}
$$

since the integrand is even.

We also have $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt \pi$, so with the definition of the Gamma function it follows that

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( 2\, e^{-x^2} - \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x} \right) \,\mathrm d x \,\,\, = \,\,\, 0
$$

although the integrand is nonzero almost everywhere.

My question: Can this be easily derived by looking at the last integral alone? Is there a transformation that turns the integral into something that is "obviously" zero?

Comment: for last integral,let $\sqrt x=t\implies dx=2t\ dt$ $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}\ dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t^2}}{t}(2t\ dt)=\int_0^{\infty}2e^{-t^2}\ dt$$ which is obviously same as the first integral:  $\int_0^{\infty}2e^{-x^2}\ dx$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : try this variable change $u=x^2$ on the gaussian integrale